# How do I implement google speech to text in my Standard Java 1.8 application? (Asynchronous Speech Translation)

Tags: java, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

I have a java application that takes in some text commands, but I would like to implement the google speech API so that I can issue speech commands instead of the text input. The microphone is always running, but will only respond when I say okay Numbnuts!, then I say the command. I have been reading the google documentation, but I still need help. Actual Code will be good. I have already created a service account key on google console. Thanks.

Comment: You do not need Google API, it is expensive and slow to send data over network. You need https://github.com/kitt-ai/snowboy.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at it.